Make a high low/close in range script (TradingView)
For a rolling window of candles of an input amount, and input draw period forward, I'd like to draw high/low lines from candle open/close values. This would look similar to the following script:
https://www.tradingview.com/v/d56Dtx3i/
However, I prefer plotting pivots based on open/close values, rather than at wicks.
Since this is a close source script, I've done my best to recreate it, but without great luck. The following script complains about the line.new x1 argument having too large of a value, despite x1 seemingly being no more than 25 for default input values:
// This Pine Script™ code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © OtisTheEscalator

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
// © OtisTheEscalator

pivotPeriod = input(5)
drawPeriod = input(15)

// This is gross, might be able to do this better with bars since higher timeframe bar change
// for timeframes on the yearly basis, but for weekly and faster charts this is fine:
barsSinceBeginingOfYear = ta.barssince(timeframe.change("3M"))

// Flesh out idea: ranges are plotted based on whether they're at modulo zero
// plus range, and plotted forward by drawPeriod

// Since low/high can be at end of range, let's start lookback at range + draw period:

pivotRangeIndex = math.floor((barsSinceBeginingOfYear - pivotPeriod - drawPeriod) / barsSinceBeginingOfYear)
startIndex = drawPeriod + pivotPeriod
lastHigh = 0.0
highIndex = 0
lastLow = 9999999.0
lowIndex = 0
for index = 0 to pivotPeriod

    inRange = math.floor((barsSinceBeginingOfYear - pivotPeriod - drawPeriod + index) / barsSinceBeginingOfYear) == pivotRangeIndex
    
    if inRange
        offset = index + pivotPeriod + drawPeriod
        if open[offset] < lastLow
            lastLow := open[offset]
            lowIndex := offset
        if open[offset] > lastHigh
            lastHigh := open[offset]
            highIndex := offset
        if close[offset] < lastLow
            lastLow := open[offset]
            lowIndex := offset
        if close[offset] > lastHigh
            lastHigh := open[offset]
            highIndex := offset

//plot(lowIndex, "lowIndex")
line.new(lowIndex, lastLow, 0, lastLow, xloc.bar_index, extend.none, color.blue, line.style_solid, 1)
//plot(lastHigh, style=plot.style_stepline, linewidth=1, color= color.blue)
plot(lastLow, style=plot.style_stepline, linewidth=3, color= color.green)

The following script does something similar, and is open source. However, it also uses the highest/lowest candle value, rather than the open/close values only, and doesn't have a plot-forward input:
https://www.tradingview.com/v/hVEw5qxv/
